# how to change variable into a clause

Tags: php, variables, boolean, colorbox, clause

I have the following problem: I have a registration form. The response message will be shown by a javascript function (colorbox) that will be called via a php variable.

It looks like:

```
<?php if ($result):?>
  <script type="text/javascript">no need to post, it is working fine</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

That variable is not working how it should do. If I set:

```
<?php if **(isset($_POST['submitted']))**: ?>
  <script type="text/javascript"> no need to post it is working</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

it works fine.

The problem is that when I'm going to submit the form. The box starts even if the registration form is not filled out correctly. To avoid that problem I thought I have to find a variable that is like a boolean true or false, if that form is filled in the right way which answer comes from my server. My thoughts were like:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tabelle (x1, x2...) VALUES('$x1','$x2')") 
       or die (mysql_error()); 

if ($result = mysql_affected_rows() = 2) {
  return TRUE;
} 

$result = mysql_affected_rows(); 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

In that way I would have changed the variable `$result` into a clause that should work. It doesn't. :(

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd start by checking the = operators in if ($result = mysql_affected_rows() = 2). Perhaps you mean if ($result = mysql_affected_rows() == 2) ?

Comment: How is your database related to your validation?

Comment: my fault. i changed this while i was copying origin is ">15" is true. i changed that because i have 17 issues to be posted. just to show example i liked to shorten it a bit.

Comment: database is related with include_once that all works fine. the php part is doing its job correctly. the main goal was just to create an response message, that is up to this point included over a div into that page. that is not quite modern. i like to refresh the whole template of my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tabelle (x1, x2...) VALUES('$x1','$x2')") 
       or die (mysql_error()); 

if ($result = mysql_affected_rows() = 2) {
  return TRUE;
} 

$result = mysql_affected_rows(); 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

why are you returning TRUE? If that is done, it won't get to the lines that come after.

Also you are using $sql in `mysql_query($sql)` which is already a mysql result resource.

If you want to show that on success of query

```
<?php
  ..
   $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tabelle (x1, x2...) VALUES('$x1','$x2')") 
       or die (mysql_error()); 

if (mysql_affected_rows() == 2){ ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">no need to post, it is working fine</script>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: hello, this doesnt work either. while trying that code, the first problem is that when i divide the php part into 2 pieces with an inserted javascript the rest of the whole code seems to be a syntax failure. every script will be marked as syntax failure.

Comment: when i change back to only one part with that mysql_affected_rows and '<?php if (mysql_affected_rows() == 7): ?>script<? endif;>' it will echo this message:'Warning: mysql_affected_rows() [function.mysql-affected-rows]: A link to the server could not be established'

Comment: that seems to be something related to your connection with the database. make sure about the driver you are using mysql / mysqli. are you able to execute any other query and fetch rows beside this case?

Answer (score 0):

You have alot wrong with this code.

Do it like this:

```
<?PHP
$success = false;
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tabelle (x1, x2...) VALUES('$x1','$x2')") or die (mysql_error()); 
if ($affected = mysql_affected_rows() == 2) { $success = true; }
?>
<?PHP if ($success){ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">no need to post, it is working fine</script>
<?PHP } ?>
```

Sorry if that doesnt completely work, you kind of confused me with the isset($_POST['submitted']) part and your question wasn't entirely clear.

Comment: hello and thanks for answer. your code isn´t working. i´m sorry when i confused you. just to add with the isset() that isset means the clause from the whole php. you could also write isset($_POST['x1']) x1 is a variable that is defined by an formfield. that means if that variable will be posted, the box opens. i had another way found out but even that seems not the write way. when i going to set isset($_POST['x1']) && $_POST['x2'] -> all variables it works but not in the correct way. thanks

Answer (score 0):

just to show the entire code. all of the following querys are working.

```
    <?php

$errorMsg = "";
$x1 = "";
$x2 = "";
$x3 = "";
$x4 = "";
$email = "";
$password = "";
$x7= "";

if (isset ($_POST['x1'])){

     $x1 = $_POST['x1'];
     $x2 = $_POST['x2'];
     $x3 = $_POST['x3'];
     $x4 = $_POST['x4'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $password = $_POST['password'];
     $x7= $_POST['x7'];

         $x1 = stripslashes($x1);
     $x2 = stripslashes($x2);
         $x3 = stripslashes($x3);
     $x4 = stripslashes($x4);
     $email = stripslashes($email);
     $password = stripslashes($password);
     $x7= stripslashes($x7);

         $x1 = strip_tags($x1);
     $x2 = strip_tags($x2);
     $x3 = strip_tags($x3);
     $x4 = strip_tags($x4);
     $email = strip_tags($email);
     $password = strip_tags($password);
     $x7= strip_tags($x7);

     include_once "scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
     $emailCHecker = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
     $emailCHecker = eregi_replace("`", "", $emailCHecker); 

     $sql_email_check = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM tablename WHERE email='$emailCHecker'"); 

     $email_check = mysql_num_rows($sql_email_check); 

     if ((!$x1) || (!$x2) || (!$x3) || (!$x4) || (!$email) || (!$password) || (!$x7)) { 

     $errorMsg = 'following issues are missing<br />';

    if(!$x1){ 
       $errorMsg .= ' *x1<br />'; 
     } 
     if(!$x2){ 
       $errorMsg .= ' *x2<br />';
     } 
     if(!$x3){ 
       $errorMsg .= ' *x3<br />';
     } 
     if(!$x4){ 
       $errorMsg .= ' *x4<br />'; 
     } 
     if(!$email){ 
       $errorMsg .= ' *email<br />'; 
     }
     if(!$x7){ 
       $errorMsg .= ' *x7<br />'; 
     }  

     } else if ($email_check > 0){ 
       $errorMsg = "Mail already exists"; 

     } else 

     { 

     $x1 = mysql_real_escape_string($x1);
     $x2 = mysql_real_escape_string($x2);
     $x3 = mysql_real_escape_string($x3);
         $x4 = mysql_real_escape_string($x4);
     $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
     $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

     $x1 = eregi_replace("`", "", $x1);
     $x2 = eregi_replace("`", "", $x2);
     $x3 = eregi_replace("`", "", $x3);
     $x4 = eregi_replace("`", "", $x4);
     $email = eregi_replace("`", "", $email);

     $db_password = md5($password); 

     $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename (x1, x2, x3, x4, sign_up_date, email, password)    

     VALUES('$x1','$x2','$x3','$x4', now(), '$email','$db_password')")  

     or die (mysql_error()); 

     $id = mysql_insert_id();

     /*mkdir("members/$id", 0755); */

    $to = "$email"; 

    $from = "xxx@xxx.xx";       
    $subject = "activationlink";        

    $message = "Link for activation";

    $headers  = "From: $from\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text\r\n";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

   $msgToUser = "text";


   /*include_once 'msgToUser.php';  */



   exit();

   } 

} else { 

      $errorMsg = "Errormessages";
          $x1 = "";
      $x2 = "";
      $x3 = "";
      $x4 = "";
      $email = "";
      $password = "";
      $x7 = "";


}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>XXXX</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/colorbox.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>   

<?php if **a variable or clause will be true: ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $.colorbox({iframe:true, scrolling:false, href:"#$msgToUser.php", innerWidth:"408px", innerHeight:"292px", opacity:0.75, overlayClose:false, escKey:false, });
        });
        $("#colorboxCloseBtn").click(function() {
        $.colorbox.close();
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
        /* Automatically resize to content 
        var y = $(document.body).height();
        var x = $(document).width();
        parent.$.colorbox.resize({innerWidth:x, innerHeight:y});*/

        $("#button_cancel").click(function() {
        parent.$.colorbox.close();
        return false;
        })
        });
        </script> 
 <?php endif; ?>
```